# Recycle bin on transplanted drive

Tags: windows-10, ntfs

I built a new machine (Windows 10), but I transplanted 2 HDDs from my old machine to the new one.  (not the boot drive, that is a new drive)

I noticed that on the new build, the recycle bin doesn't display files that I deleted before I moved the drives to the new computer. I was definitely using the recycle bin on the old computer, in fact I restored a file just the other day.

I suspect that this is a permissions problem (I have already had to take ownership of some other folders because they had permissions associated that were from the old machine).

How do I regain access to the recycle bins?

Hardware information:

- This is a home installation, so no Domains or AD are involved
- Both machines were running Windows 10 Pro
- The drives are formatted NTFS

Answer (score 1):

Because the system was rebuilt the user account may have the same username but it will have a different UUID and the recycling bin is tied to the users UUID.

Each partition will have a hidden system folder under it called `$Recycle.Bin` with folders under it for each user. You would need to access the recycle bin folder and then find which folder under it had the files you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Recycle Bins are per-user, not system-wide. In addition, they are broken up among the drives you deleted files from. You will need to make sure the drive the files were deleted from are hooked up.

After that, change your folder view settings to show hidden files, and system protected files. Next, take ownership of the "$Recycle.Bin" folder in the root of the drive(s) and give yourself full permissions. From here, you will have to jump into an elevated command prompt and navigate to the "$Recycle.Bin" folder (The sub-folders may not be visible in Explorer, but they are in CMD). Each sub-folder in that folder correlates to a different user from your old system. Your old deleted files should be located within.

Comment: Thats not entirely true. The recyclebin is stored as Drive:\$Recycle.Bin and files deleted on a specific drive will have this folder in their root. It does store per user settings, but if the copy was done succesfully they should still be in there, though possibly not visible without special tools or the command prompt.

Comment: I stand corrected. I was previously under the impression the bin was just on the system drive, but it looks more like the OS uses junctions in the background to link them together.

Comment: So this didn't hurt me because I have backups (I mainly wanted to close that loop of knowing there were inaccessible recycle bin files out there.  BUT, when i took ownership of the $Recycle.Bin folder, I also selected "replace permissions on children", and I ended up losing everything in there.  After the operation completed, I got a dialog stating that "the recycle bin on Drive D is corrupted, do you want to delete it".  In my case, I knew I wasn't losing anything important, so I went ahead and let windows delete it.