# What tasks should you perform when you transplant an NTFS drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs

I recently asked this question: [Recycle bin on transplanted drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1150358/recycle-bin-on-transplanted-drive)

And it got me thinking:  What other housecleaning sorts of tasks should you perform before and after you transplant an NTFS drive to a new machine.

Examples:

I lost my recycle bins (see above), but if I hadn't noticed, then all of the files in the bin would have remained hidden to me (and would most likely never have been reclaimed, so it would have been "lost" disk space.

Also, I've had to fight with permissions issues in the past when moving volumes that contain teh Users/Documents, Photos, etc folders (I like to keep my user data on a separate volume from my system drive).

Is there a set of recommended procedures for moving volumes?